# Trying to replace table with divs but with partial success

Tags: html, css

Trying to do simple header for website, [image][text][splitted horizontal section]:

```
<div style="width: 930px;">
<div style="width: 280px; height: 80px; display: inline; background-color: red;">image</a></div>
<div style="width: 400px; height: 80px; display: inline; background-color: blue;">text</div>
<div style="width: 250px; height: 80px; display: inline; background-color: green;">
<div style="text-align: right; height: 40px; background-color: gray;">some bar</div>
<div style="text-align: right; height: 30px; background-color: yellow;">some buttons </div>
</div>
</div>
```

What I see in VS2010 and IE8:
[image]

What I see in Chrome and FireFox:
[image]

Why? And how to fix it? I need the first variant of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add float: left to your inline elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmKaU/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
<div style="width: 930px;">
    <div style="display: block; float:left; width: 280px; height: 80px; background-color: red;">image</a></div>
    <div style="display: block; float:left; width: 400px; height: 80px; display: block; background-color: blue;">text</div>
    <div style="display: block; float:right; width: 250px; height: 80px; display: block; background-color: green;">
        <div style="text-align: right; height: 40px; background-color: gray;">some bar</div>
        <div style="text-align: right; height: 30px; background-color: yellow;">some buttons </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between float left and float right in the last, splitted div?

Comment: You could also use left in this case.
I think I just put that in this way. There is no specific reason. Hope it's helpful.